# Minecraft won't open for no apparent reason

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues, macos

I recently downloaded Minecraft on a new computer (a Mac OSX) and it was working for a week until, all the sudden, Opening the game just immediately exits and a pop-up comes up and says

> Minecraft Lancher quit unexpectedly

Clicking "Report to Apple" is just says this

```
Process:         launcher [621]
Path:            /Applications/Minecraft.app/Contents/MacOS/launcher
Identifier:      com.mojang.intdev.minecraftlauncher
Version:         1235 (1)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [148]
User ID:         502

Date/Time:       2017-02-21 18:11:35.773 -0500
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.8.5 (12F2560)
Report Version:  10

Interval Since Last Report:          230750 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           120
Per-App Interval Since Last Report:  32 sec
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   22
Anonymous UUID:                      650BF36B-C0E6-3BE4-8640-EE89B352963B

Crashed Thread:  0  CrBrowserMain  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000040
```

(I couldn't fit the rest)

I've tried everything,

- Installing java, (Its up to date)
- Installing OpenGL, (Which apparently, has no download for Macs)
- reinstalling the game.

Comment: Do you have a Minecraft crash log that you can post?

Comment: Unfortunately you cut off the relevant part of the crash log. Please edit your question to include the whole file. I might know the problem, but need to be sure about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just download the old minecraft launcher at http://launcher.mojang.com/download/Minecraft_legacy.dmg

At the title screen it should say that java is outdated and that you will need to install java 8 even though you have Java 8 installed. Do not listen to this for now. I am also running the exact same version of macOS 10.8.5

The same thing happened to me. I think it was my antivirus that screwed the new minecraft launcher.